# cuda libraries for search operations

Tags: search, cuda

Is there any CUDA library that performs comparison/search operation.

Comment: Too vague - you need to be a bit more specific about your requirements - what kind of search ? what data type(s) ? how large is the data and how is it organised (1D array ? 2D array ? other ?) ?

Answer (score 1):

CUDA is an API for creating libraries that run on the NVidia GPU.  Consequently, any operations that are to be performed must be custom programmed. There are not a wide range of open-source libraries available.

Programmers use 'C for CUDA' (C with NVIDIA extensions), compiled through a PathScale Open64 C compiler, to code algorithms for execution on the GPU.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [Thrust](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/), which includes a binary_search operation and is very easy to use.